# OpenIdConnectAuthentication SaveTokens makes Request.IsAuthenticated = false

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, openid-connect, katana

My application is an ASP.NET (.net framework 4.7) web forms app and I am using CookieAuthentication and OpenIdConnect authentication to authenticate against Azure Active Directory. I also need to retrieve access_token in order to call a downstream API.

The corresponding app registrations are created and configured. The Client app registration has both: issue Access Tokens and ID tokens, and the API app registration has a configured scope that is added in my client app **OpenIdConnectAuthentication** configuration.

So far it looks like the first part of the workflow (authenticating the user to access the web forms app) is working just fine, an even when I add "RedeemToken = true" in my OpenIdCOnnectAuthentication middleware, the application still seems fine with no issues. However, as soon as I set "SaveTokens = true" my "Request.IsAuthenticated" property is always "false".

Below is my current configuration:

OWIN Middleware Configuration

```
  app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            CookieManager = new SystemWebCookieManager()
        });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                ClientSecret = "clientSecret",
                Authority = authority,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                RedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,

                ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code,                    
                SaveTokens = true,                    
                Scope = "openid offline_access api://<api>/api-access",
                RedeemCode = true
            });
```

Checking if the Request is authenticated to then retrieve the access_token

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var result = Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.AuthenticateAsync("Cookies").Result;
            string token = result.Properties.Dictionary["access_token"];
        } 
    }
```

If I remove "SaveTokens = true" then Request.IsAuthenticated is set up properly but I cannot access tokens.

Any idea how SaveTokens might be impacting the value of Request.IsAuthenticated or what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When is Page_Load run with respect to the authentication.  Which is done first? Request.IsAuthenticated is a global variable and you have no idea when it is going to get set with respect to the authentication.  Is this code running on client or server?

Comment: @jdweng Page_Load is in my default.aspx page, which is the first page the user accesses. In the first attempt Page_Load will be called before the user is Authenticated, but if not authenticated the OpenIdConnect authentication challenge is issued and after the user enters his credentials he gets re-directed to the "Redirect URI" which is gain Default.aspx but this time Request.IsAuthenticated is supposed to be true. If I removed "SaveTokens = true" from the OpenIdConnectAuthentication configuration, then it works as expected.

Comment: I think when you do not SaveTokens you are using an old token. Don't get fooled.  The code is not working.

Comment: Could be that your session cookie is too large and rejected, so you are not considered logged in?

Comment: @ToreNestenius it might be the case, because I even disabled SaveTokens and store them manually in the Identity Claims and I see the same behavior. Any insights on how might be the right way to do it, is there a way to retrieve the access token on the fly, instead of saving them beforehand?

Comment: Usually, the OpenIDConnect handler, pases the auth information to the cookie handler, for persistence inside the session cookie. But you can also choose to store the tokenselsewhere. But someone you must store the tokens somewhere, tied to the current user.  you can add a SessionStore to the cookie handler,  to store the tokens in a database and hence reducing the size of the session cookie. but usually, if the tokens are large, the session cookie is then split into multiple cookies.

do check what is stored in the browser for your domain.